# Magic Carpet effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do something like a magic carpet on my game, basically I have a plane where I added a carpet texture, but now I want to do something that I have no idea how to approach and where to start, I want to make the carpet to move like the trigonometry sin, without leaving the place I want that effect, like a wave, but I did not find any tipe online,

**I tried something like this**

```
public float amplitude;
public float speed;
private float tempVal;
private Vector3 tempPos;

void Start()
{
    tempVal = transform.position.y;
}

void Update()
{
    tempPos.y = tempVal + amplitude * Mathf.Sin (speed * Time.time);
    transform.position = tempPos;
}
```

I could make my carpet do the sin movement, but i dont want my object to leave the place, i want my carpet to deform and do a movement like a wave.

Sorry if my explanation was not the best and sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Comment: You have two options: Either 3D-model a carpet and give it an animation in which it does the wave-deformation movement and trigger the animation in Unity OR use C# and Unity to display every vertex in the model. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html)

Comment: Maximilian solution are some of the many. Another solution could be to use a specific vertex shader to obtain the same effect. (Unless you have to move something upon the carpet, in that case, it might be complicated to do that with a simple shader)